# Question about vectors (player velocity) and Spigot API

Tags: java, vector, velocity, bukkit, spigot

I can’t understand how I can push the player back, left and right, I only understood how to push the player to the side where he is looking.

I tried to use ChatGPT but it produced code that doesn't work as expected.

Please tell me!

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you show the code that isn't working, what you tried etc? You can take the [tour] and see [ask] to make question with more details that we can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `player.setVelocity(new Vector(x, y, z));`. To throw player up, you can do `player.setVelocity(new Vector(0, 1, 0));` etc.